# ORA-00923 dot net core devart provider FirstOrDefault() query error

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, asp.net-core, devart

I'm developing a .net core web API which use database oracle and data provider devart when I try to get some data on login operation I have a this problem

```
{"ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"}
```

my code drop catch on this line throw exception

```
var result = db.tables.Where(x => x.code== userParams.code&& x.password == userParams.Password).FirstOrDefault();
```

I changed after the where funtion
 I tried

```
.First()
.SingleOrDefault()
.FirstOrDefault()
```

Also, I tried then that worked but I think this functions illogical

```
.SingleOrDefault()
.Take(1)
```

My versions

```
.net core 3.1
OracleDB version 11g
EFCore Devart 
EF 3.1
```

Anyone can know anything about this problem?

Comment: is "code" your primary key? Or how is your relations defined?

Comment: No code like a nickname or username

Comment: Confirm that you are using the newest build https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore/9.10.909. If this doesn't help, enable the dbMonitor tool and specify the SQL statement that fails to execute: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?dbmonitor.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Devart I updated my `Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore`  version ith this version. It worked now :)
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore/9.10.909

Answer (score 0):

If SingleOrDefault is working i would redifne your query like this

```
var result = db.tables.SingleOrDefault(x => x.code == userParams.code && x.password == userParams.Password);
```

By doing so, i also think you are skipping som unnecessarily sub querying.

Comment: SingleOrDefault didn't working. Same "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected'